# Android Studio Notification Lights

Tags: android, android-notifications

Why are the LED Lights not working with this Notification?

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setDefaults(0)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getData().get("username"))
                .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody())
                .setVibrate(new long[]{1500, 0, 1500, 0})
                .setLights(Color.BLUE, 2000, 1000)
                .setWhen(remoteMessage.getSentTime())
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody()))
                .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Can you help? I cant find the error.

I put the notificationBuilder.setDefaults(0) on top but it is still not working

Comment: You need to either set the defaults to 0 for API level below 26 and for above 26 you have to set enableLights to true

Comment: notificationBuilder.defaults = 0; for pre 26

and 

notificationBuilder.enableLights(true); for post 26 version

Comment: i updated my code like you said. But it is still not working

Comment: and also when i set the vibration longer it does not change